# selecting and displaying rows from different date values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get rows from a table based on different dates. Although values of the dates are not always the same.

Basically I have to get first what are the range of the dates and then extract the rows of the columns based on those dates.

I cant do `SELECT COUNT(location) FROM tweets WHERE date<= NOW()` or `date<=2012-07-29 17:38:32`

cause as I said dates are not fixed. I DON'T PUT THE DATES but they are dynamically created.

Comment: Clarify your question, please

Comment: How are the dates dynamically created? Can't you just pass the date variable to the query?

Comment: i dont know how much more clarification can it take. this is for graph visualization . i want to visualize how many times a tweet has been posted FROM SAME countries WITHIN different dates.

Comment: Why can't you use placeholders and supply date values?

Comment: is there a way to store the range of date values from db in an array and then extract rows of table within those date values??

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Generally you specify your query with placeholders like `WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?` and fill in those `?` placeholders with values using `mysqli` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the crux of this is how the dates are generated but the query is simple:

```
$start = '2012-6-24';
$end   = '2012-7-24';

"SELECT COUNT(location) FROM tweets WHERE date between '$start' and '$end'";
```